# Does anyone have an example of using parmest and pyomo.dae together?

Tags: pyomo

I know the Sandia team has presented on this before. We are curious if there are any public examples of code. I could not find any on GitHub.com in the Pyomo/pyomo repository.

Alex

P.S. These examples for parmest are very helpful. (https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/tree/master/pyomo/contrib/parmest/examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semibatch example in the Pyomo repo uses Pyomo.DAE. See [this link](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/pyomo/contrib/parmest/examples/semibatch/semibatch.py) for the model and [this link](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/pyomo/contrib/parmest/examples/semibatch/semibatch_parmest.py) for the parmest usage.